# RESTful routing in Rails 3 app - some advice / pointers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app, locally in development without a subfolder, and in production i have it deployed under /myappname/

So, locally I have http://myapp.dev and in production http://mydomain.com/myappname

which my root route does:

```
root :to => 'products#list'
```

which works great, even in production.

Now, i have a default match action:

```
match '/:controller(/:action(/:id))'
```

which breaks in production, so i started trying to build a restful route, but i need some help... I can't wrap my head around the routing. I think i have the proper start (with scope, below)

```
#PRODUCTION ROUTES
scope '/myappname' do
    #WHAT WOULD GO HERE?
end
```

format would be /myappname/products/show/15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  #PRODUCTION ROUTES
  scope "/mothers" do
    #ROOT
    root :to => 'rings#list'
    match '/rings/:id' => "rings#show", :as => :ring
  end

  #DEVELOPMENT ROUTES
  root :to => 'rings#list'
  match '/rings/:id' => "rings#show", :as => :ring
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm. I would expect all the routes to work relative to the "home page", so why don't you just go with

```
  resources :users
```

or any other route definition from the examples in config/routes.rb?